# How to tackle the general solution of this ODE.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm attempting to find the general solution to this problem and then find the particular solution using the initial conditions.

$$y' + (x+1)y = e^{x^2}y^3,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, y(0) = 0.5$$

I'm not sure on how to approach this problem, can anyone tell me the method needed to simplify this, or any tricks I could use to make the solution more obvious.

I was thinking some sort of substitution was necessary but again I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$y' + (x+1)y = e^{x^2}y^3$

It's a Bernouilli differential equation : $y'+\alpha(x)y=\beta(x)y^m$

$ \frac {y'}{y^3} + (x+1)\frac 1 {y^2}= e^{x^2}$

Substitute $z(x)=\frac 1 {y^2}$ then $z'(x)=-2y^{-3}y'(x)$

$ -\frac {z'(x)} 2 + (x+1)z(x)= e^{x^2}$

$ z'(x) -2(x+1)z(x)=-2e^{x^2}$

......Can you solve it now ?

Comment: Bernoulli's Differential Equation isn't covered in my course, so I've got no idea about it. I just assumed it was another differential equation.

Comment: @Jack I see but it's simple once you substitue z(x) to y(x) it becomes an ordinary first order differential equation ...